# Format/Layout for cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, syntax

I got a lot of help regarding this issue earlier but the issue hasnt been completely resolved for me. I am stuck at another thing now. I am returning a response from my controller and receiving it in the Index.cshtml like this:

```
var rData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.WarehouseResults));
```

Now I need to assign this data to slickgrid somewhat like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var from = 0, to = from + rData.length;
//data.length = parseInt(resp.total);
for (var i = 0; i < rData.length; i++) {
    data[from + i] = rData[i];
    data[from + i].index = from + i;
}

onDataLoaded.notify({ from: from, to: to });

   grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", rData, columns, options);

 etc etc...

</script>
```

Now, the problem is, I dont know where exactly to receive the data. As in, where do I put this line:

```
var rData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.WarehouseResults));
```

If I put it above the  tag (but inside the @Scripts section), I get an error saying rData is not defined. Then when I put it inside the  tag, I get a syntax error saying: "IHtmlString HtmlHelper.Raw(String value) (+1 overloads) returns markup that is not HTML encoded".

Where exactly should this line go? Is there a standard format for a cshtml page, like which sections go where? If so, can someone provide a link or something for it?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code in MVC 5:-

```
var rData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.WarehouseResults));
```

I find that the semi-colon at the end of the line causes a syntax error.

A solution which I am currently using (my example is for JQuery autocomplete) which should also work for your example is as follows.

Create the javascript variable code completely within the HtmlHelper. This is placed within the view's @section Scripts.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @Html.Raw("var existingPersons = " +  Json.Encode(this.Model.ExistingPersons) + ";" )
        @Html.Raw("var settlementInformation="  + Json.Encode(this.Model.SettlementInformation) + ";")

        $(function () {
            $("#personName").autocomplete({
                source: existingPersons
            });

            $("#settlementInformation").autocomplete({
                source: settlementInformation
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

---

At the client side this appears in the `<head>` element as expected

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var existingPersons = ["Person 1","Person 2"];
    var settlementInformation=["Settlement Type 1"];

    $(function () {
        $("#personName").autocomplete({
            source: existingPersons
        });

        $("#settlementInformation").autocomplete({
            source: settlementInformation
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've not tried this in other versions of MVC